# Toggle a menu from the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, master-pages

I am trying to get a menu to slide from the left when I click on a link. I have been following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckNx9/6/) without success. The div remains in one spot and does not slide. Based on the example the div should be hidden and slide into view with click then slide out when I click again. It starts off hidden then comes into view without sliding and does not slide back. I am very new to jQuery, but have been studying very hard.

In my master page I have set the scripts for the page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>     
<script type="text/javascript"  >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
      $("#slider").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left",
        distance: 280
      }, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
<a id="click" href="#" runat="server" style="position:relative;top:0px;">Slide</a>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="box">
  <div id="slider" runat="server" class=" divColCtr RoundBorder" style="display:none">
   //controls inside here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is the problem that I am trying this on the master page? I need a menu for each page and would hate to think I have to add to each, but if so then that is fine.

Comment: Is there any error in the console ? The fiddle is working .. Once the javascript jquery library is loaded and this doc.ready on each page, you can just have a menu page included however way you are using your view engine.

Comment: Everything looks to be sliding just fine in your fiddle...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A requirement for the fiddle you are trying to replicate is : jQuery UI 1.9.2

This can be downloaded here : http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/11/jquery-ui-1-9-2/

On the left side of the jsFiddle you can see external requirements/dependencies

Include this just after your jquery reference and it should be fine.

Try this as your code :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" ></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" 
></script> 


<script type="text/javascript"  >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
      $("#slider").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left",
        distance: 280
      }, 500);
    });
  });
</script>
<a id="click" href="#" runat="server" style="position:relative;top:0px;">Slide</a>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="box">
  <div id="slider" runat="server" class=" divColCtr RoundBorder" style="display:none">
   //controls inside here
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I downloaded the Development Bundle and now I am really unsure what file in there to reference.

Comment: Ok you only need the jquery-ui,min.js file reference -> See the top of my code example @DonA you can extract the file from the downloaded package and add it to your local repository folder and reference it the same way you have reference jquery -> Just remember to add the reference AFTER jquery as it depends on it.

Comment: I removed the top reference to the 1.11.1.js file, added yours and no sliding, heck my link does not even show up now.

Comment: @DonA do not remove your reference to 1.11.1 ! You need that! Just add the EXTRA reference! :) -JQuery needs to load up first -> Then JqureyUI.

Comment: OK, but that was the wrong version, and I copied the compressed js and pasted it in that file - hoping to fix it.

Comment: @DonA i have edited the code to use completely remote source, so its 100% standalone -> Copy it and create a brand new HTML file with it and it will work for you. It sounds like you're having a reference error.

Comment: @DonA not at all, i know how tedious JS can be sometimes!